# Error in creating pdf file using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have one Gridview in my asp .Net project (c#) and i want to export it to pdf
for this purpose i'm using iTextSharp as bellow:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)

{ /* Do nothing */ }

protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Clear(); //this clears the Response of any headers or previous output
    Response.Buffer = true; //ma
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.pdf");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    ASPxGridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();

    htmlparser.Parse(sr);

    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);

    Response.End();  



}
```

when i test it , i get this error:

> The UNC path should be of the form \server\share

anybody pls help me?